# Where are the beige pants in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Seriously. I want them for Franklin, by the way. Not the shorts. Not the cargo pants. Just pants. They exist according to [this](http://gta.wikia.com/Clothing_in_GTA_V/Franklin#.E2.80.8BSuit_Pants).

I am playing on the PC.

Comment: Most likely, they are in Posonbys.

Comment: You can't buy pants in Posonbys though, can you? You can only get them if you're buying a full suit, but the 3-Piece Beige Suit includes tan pants.

Comment: When you walk in, go right and you'll see a wall. Go to the rightmost clothing item (IIRC, those bring up the pants menu) - it's been a while since I've played the game, so maybe wrong.

Comment: No, it's shirts. There's a pair of pants, but they don't bring up a pants menu.

Comment: "Go to Suburban and there is a rack by the cash out that has cargo pants and stuff. Then on the back wall there are shelves of denim, it even says denim above it. Bam you will have pants!" - found this on net maybe that helps?

Comment: @Nitro.de No, those are just jeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out beige pants aren't available in the PC version of GTAV. They're most likely just renamed tan pants.

Answer (score 5):

First off you will want to go to Ponsonbys (I went to this one).[image: Map] Enter and go to the back left wall(white with three suit models). Browse the suits and you will see that there is a beige suit, buy it.[image] Now go somewhere that you are able to change clothes. Open the suit menu and select suit pants, you should then be able to wear your new pair of beige slacks.[image] It seems that you aren't able to simply buy beige pants on their own, you must buy the entire suit. You will also not be able to wear the beige pants in some combinations of clothes such as with the boots for example (they will switch to a pair of jeans).

Note this is done on the latest update for GTA V.

Comment: Beige suit gives you tan pants. Don't know why.

Comment: I can confirm that I went and purchased a Beige suit and received beige pants from Ponsonbys. Are you sure you are buying the beige suit? and have you tried every Ponsonbys?

Comment: I haven't tried every Ponsonbys. I'll check again in a couple hours, and get screenshots if I can. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, unless there has been a patch that changed the pants in the last month that I updated, which I doubt, you should be able to get them from the 3 piece beige suit. Also, I change his clothes at the safe house Franklin receives from the campaign but I don't think that would make any difference.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aradplaug/screenshots/?appid=271590) You can just ignore the last image.

Comment: Well I am guessing that this is a cross platform difference as you are using a pc version where as mine is on an xbox 360. I would suggest mentioning this in your question as the gta v tag is for all platforms. This is the only reason that I can see for this to be happening and unfortunately you **may** not be able to purchase Beige pants in the pc version of the game.

Comment: No worries, it sucks that you can't get them though.

Answer (score 3):

At this Ponsonbys they have *beige chinos*:

[image: ponsonbys]
[image: beige chinos]

At Suburban they have *brown skinny jeans* that look beige:

[image: brown skinny jeans]

Same store also has these *brown jeans* that look beige:

[image: brown jeans]